# unexpected bash behaviour after console login (openSUSE)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, opensuse

I'm trying to install a Linux OS on the computer I use as a home server, because I liked "Raspbian" so much on my Raspberry Pi. I created a custom linux using openSUSE Studio, that's just text based and very simple, to squeeze all the performance I can out of the machine. I was expecting something like Rasbian, where it boots and you log in, and can use `sudo` and `startx` to get into the desktop, however on Debian and on the openSUSE, it boots to `bash`. How can I get out of `bash` and into the (terminal?), so I can use `apt-get`, `sudo`, and all that.

I know I need to look into how linux works first, but my main concern is getting on on the machine and installing software, so I can get the machine closed up and in its rack.

Comment: You can do apt-get, sudo and all that from bash.  What's exactly wrong?

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem with bash? It's a shell. You can log in a shell and use commands like `sudo`, `apt-get`... And you need a shell to use the terminal. Otherwise, it's just a black window which doesn't answer when you type a command.

Comment: bash as a shell runs under a terminal... When installing openSUSE you can configure whether automatic login shall happen. I know that from X only not for the console. Do I understand you correctly: You start the PC and get to a shell prompt without enterting user name and password?

Comment: @PatriceLevesque I must be doing something wrong, after boot I log in as root user and BASH spits an error if I enter any commands: http://i.imgur.com/l8IeOlD.png

Comment: SUSE AFAICT is not using the debian package format (thus is not using apt-get); it's a RPM-based system.  Please check the documentation for openSUSE: http://en.opensuse.org/Package_management

Comment: @PatriceLevesque Ok, not a good image. I can understand why that would not work, however typing "sudo" returns the same error on either OS's, also.

Comment: sudo is not part of a default install everywhere.  You're root, so you don't need sudo to install sudo... if you really want it.

Comment: @PatriceLevesque Thank you, I understand now.